# Usage of this.hetWritableDatabase in android

Tags: java, android

Can someone explain clearly this line of code for me? and where we need to use this code?

public class DataHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

.
.
.
.
.

SQLiteDatabase sql = this.getWritablrDatabase;

Comment: I suggest you read a tutorial about SQLite databases on Android. There is a lot of information about this on the Internet.

Comment: Also, I suggest you copy and paste the code from wherever you saw this. By typing it, you have introduced many errors.

Comment: Finally, which part do you not understand? Do you know about declaring field variables in Java? Do you understand initializing fields? Do you know what `this` means? Do you know how to call a method? Do you need to know what the `getWritableDatabase()` method does? Please ask more specific questions.

Comment: I just can't understand the "getWritableDatabase() .

Comment: As I said in my first comment, there are many online tutorials that explain using a SQLite database on Android. I suggest you google a little and read them. You should also familiarize yourself with the API docs at http://developer.android.com. This documentation explains this method very clearly.

Answer (score 0):

if you want delete from database then you can use this like

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("delete from  " + tablename);
```

Or you add some thing. that means if you want write some thing like insert, delete sou you will need it...

Comment: When i want to create my own sqlite database, i can not create it without this line of code, Why? What does do this code? Explain it for me...tnx.

Comment: if you want to fetch  data from sqlite you need to open database. all other method to open database are read only.  this getWritableDatabase method return read and write permission.

Answer (score 0):

When you call this method, SQLiteOpenHelper connects to local sqlite3 database on your device and returning a new instance of SQLiteDatabase.

The difference between `getReadableDatabase()` and `getWriteableDatabase()` is simple: the first method returns you an instance of the database in **read-only** mode, while the second one allows you to execute **database transactions**: change database tables content or/and structure.